# Navbar dropdown issue, cant get 100% on links

Tags: html, css, header, dropdown, navbar

Basically the navbar works but before when hovering over the links the full width would get highlighted (the 100%). I have made some adjustments after that and now i cant get the links to highlight 100% when i hover over them, what am i missing?
my code:

Let me know or hint me, i have tried giving 100% width to the ul, li, the anchor, the container divs, but no luck.

html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head></head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/ae0153af6c.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/stylesheets/style.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/stylesheets/header.css" />
<script src="/javascripts/header.js"></script>
<title>Header</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="navbar-flexbox" id="navbar">

        <div class="hamburger">
            <!-- <a href="#" class="toggle-button "> -->
            <span class="bar"> </span>
            <span class="bar"> </span>
            <span class="bar"> </span>
            <!-- </a> -->
        </div>
        <div id="logo">
            <h1>The g<span class="title-span">oo</span>d Kitchen</h1>
        </div>

        <div class="search-wrapper">
            <form class="search-form" action="/recipes/search" method="POST">
                <div class="search-bar-container">
                    <label class="search-label" for="search"></label>
                    <input class="search-input" type="search" name="search" id="search" placeholder="What would you like to cook?">
                </div>
                <div class="search-icon-container">
                    <i class="search-icon fa-lg fa-solid fa-magnifying-glass"></i>
                </div>
                <div class="search-btn-container">
                    <input class="search-submit" type="submit" value="Search">
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>

        <div class="navigation-list-dropdown noDisplay">

            <div class="navbar-links">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="/recipes/create">Upload a recipe</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/recipes/list">All recipes</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
            </div>
            <% if(locals.islogged) { %>
                <div class="userLogged-links dropdown">
                    <button class="dropdown-btn">
                        <% if(locals.userLogged) { %>
                            <img class="user-image-miniature" src="../../images/userImages/<%=userLogged.image %>">
                            Hey user
                    </button>
                    <% } %>
                        <div class="dropdown-content navbar-links">
                            <li><a href="/user/profile">My profile</a></li>
                            <li><a href="/user/logout">Logout</a></li>
                        </div>
                </div>
                <% } else { %>
                    <div class="user-links dropdown navbar-links">
                        <li><a href="/user/login">Login</a></li>
                        <li><a href="/user/register">Register</a></li>
                    </div>
                    <% } %>

                        </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

CSS:

```
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

#navbar {
    /* background-color: #121214; cool black option */
    background-color: rgb(47, 84, 88);
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 2;
}

.menu li {
    /* font-size: 16px; */
    /* padding: 15px 5px; */
    white-space: nowrap;
}

/* ul {
    width: 100%;
} */

/* li {
    width: 100vw;
} */

.navbar-links {
    width: 100% !important;
}


.navigation-list-dropdown ul {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: wrap column;
    width: 100%;
}


.navigation-list-dropdown ul li {
    list-style: none;
}


.navigation-list-dropdown li a {
    padding: 1rem;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    font-size: 0.8rem;
}

.navigation-list-dropdown li:hover {
    background-color: #555;
}

.navigation-list-dropdown li:hover a {
    color: rgb(207, 181, 181);
}


.noDisplay {
    display: none;
}

.noVisible {
    visibility: hidden;
}


body i {
    color: black;
}




/* here the hambu menu */

.hamburger {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0.8rem;
    right: 1rem;
    /* display: flex;
    flex-direction: column; */
    /* justify-content: space-between; */
    /* height: 20px;
    width: 21px; */
}


.hamburger.active .bar:nth-child(1) {
    transform: translateY(8px) rotate(45deg)
}

.hamburger.active .bar:nth-child(2) {
    opacity: 0;
}

.hamburger.active .bar:nth-child(3) {
    transform: translateY(-8px) rotate(-45deg)
}



.bar {
    display: block;
    width: 25px;
    height: 3px;
    margin: 5px auto;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    background-color: white;
}


.navbar h1 {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}

.title-span {
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255) !important;
}

#logo h1 {
    font-family: Brush Script MT !important;
    position: relative;
    font-size: 1.7rem;
    margin: .5rem;
}

ul {
    margin: 0;
}




#navbar .hambMenu,
.login-register-container i,
#logo h1 {
    color: rgb(199, 176, 176);
}

.dropdown {
    float: left;
    overflow: initial;
}


.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    z-index: 1;

}

.dropdown-btn {
    font-size: 16px;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    color: white;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    background-color: inherit;
    font-family: inherit;
    /* Important for vertical align on mobile phones */
    margin: 0;
    /* Important for vertical align on mobile phones */
}

.dropdown-btn {
    color: white !important;
    padding: 0px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}

.dropdown-btn>* {
    padding: 0px 5px;
}

.dropdown-content a {
    float: none;
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
}


.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
}

.user-image-miniature {
    width: 35px;
    border-radius: 15px;
}

/* End of user links navbar */



.navbar-flexbox {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: flex-start;
    height: auto;

}







/* Search bar*/
.search-input {
    font-size: 0.8rem !important;
    width: 100%;
    height: 35px;
    border: 1px solid rgb(188, 180, 180);
    border-top-left-radius: 3px;
    border-top-right-radius: 3px;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
}

.search-icon-container {
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-end;
}

.search-icon {
    right: 5vw;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 2;
    color: rgb(139, 147, 146);
    align-self: center;
}

.search-wrapper {
    width: 100%;
}

.search-form {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
}

.search-label {
    display: none;
}

.search-bar-container {
    width: 100%;
}

.search-btn-container {
    display: none;

}

/* End of Search bar*/





@media (min-width:480px) {

    li {
        width: 20vw;
    }

    .hamburger {
        display: none;
    }

    .navbar-flexbox {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-between;
        align-items: center;
    }

    .navigation-list-dropdown {
        display: initial;
    }

    .navigation-list-dropdown ul {
        flex-direction: row;
        justify-content: space-evenly;
    }

    .navigation-list-dropdown ul {
        border-top: 3px solid rgb(144, 208, 221);
    }

    .user-links,
    .userLogged-links {
        display: flex !important;
        border-left: 0.1px solid rgb(144, 208, 221);
    }

    #logo h1 {
        font-size: 2rem;
    }
}

/* @media (min-width: 600px) {
    li {
        padding: 0px 10px;
    }
} */
```

Comment: Can you provide a working sample? Or a link? It's impossible to say what the issue is from the code you've provided

Comment: Hi sure https://crud-recipes.herokuapp.com
Resize it to about 300px so the hamburguer menu shows as thats whats giving me the issue once its displayed.

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue. The whole links background color changes when I hover over it. I did notice that you have a `</div>` after the `<li><a href="/">Home</a></li>` nav item that shouldn't be there.

Comment: @LearningToProgram The issue is the `align-items: flex-start` style in the `.navbar-flexbox` selector. You can use a @media query selector to make that style not apply below `300px`, or set the style to `align-items: normal`, or remove it if it doesn't impact the desktop styling.

Comment: When you click on the hamburger menu and it display the links and you hover over them 100% width changes color behind the hovered item? I have tried in chrome and safari and nothing. I just checked, that div  encloses correctly and removing It does nothing

Comment: @LearningToProgram the div with `class="navigation-list-dropdown active"` needs some more styling, it's going to need a media query though -- `.navigation-list-dropdown.active { width: 100% }` and then below that add `@media (min-width: 480px) { .navigation-list-dropdown.active { width: auto } }`

Comment: @LearningToProgram I see you already have a mobile breakpoint in your CSS. So you just need to remove the `align-items: flex-start` from the mobile `.navbar-flexbox` selector in the `header.css` file on line 215.

Comment: Thank you guys, I was missing the width 100% once the dropdown was active and also checking about the align-items flex start cheers this really fixed it!